# Code Base Analysis

Tags: refactoring, code-quality, maintenance

Does anyone know of a methodology that can be used on a project file tree to identify dead files, dead code, unused libraries, etc. I have been thinking about this for some time as I seem to inherit code that was develop from another code base and find that my maintenance reveals unneeded libs, unused files and last of all dead code.

Comment: We do not recommend tools on this site (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the only place in the SE network where you can ask such questions). But if you intend to ask there, you need to add a lot more information to your question - details about your environment, programming languag(es), operating system, your budget, etc.

Comment: Thanks. First time using the site. I have changed the offending term, keeping in line with the spirit of the question.

Comment: Details about the programming environment and languag(es) you have in mind with this question would improve it on this site as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, nearly all languages allow for runtime loading of code and/or reflection which make full static analysis impossible because the code could be used dynamically. Though those tools exist for most languages if you’re willing to live with that caveat - not a few languages/IDEs do this sort of dead code/reference analysis these days and emit warnings.

Full runtime analysis is impossible because it’s equivalent to the halting problem (is that code really dead, or has it just not been called yet?). Though those tools exist if you’re willing to live with that caveat. Depending on your situation, a simple code coverage tool (perhaps in combination with a fuzzer) might be sufficient, which come with many testing frameworks.